# Eliminate division by zero using an SQL Server CASE statement

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to eliminate this division by zero error using `CASE` in my [T-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) `SELECT` statement. For some reason, I keep getting the error. Here is my logic.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN tb1.wpf = 0.000 THEN '0.000' 
       ELSE SUM(tb2.weight/tb1.wpf) 
    END AS Average 
FROM Table1 tb1, table2 tb2 
GROUP BY tb1.wpf
```

I did not include joins and all my logic to keep my question specific to this case. How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: Perhaps this may help... http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/05/09/handling-division-by-zero-scenarios-in-t-sql/

Comment: [`CASE` is not guaranteed to short circuit when containing aggregates.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12945/3690). The `tb2.weight/tb1.wpf` can still be carried out even when `tb1.wpf = 0`. You could use `tb2.weight/NULLIF(tb1.wpf,0)`

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith.. you are a savior !

Comment: Minor points: Are you sure that's the formula you want to use?  There is a built in `AVG()` function - the one you're currently using may not get the results you expect..  Don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) - always explicitly declare your joins.

Comment: @X-Zero thanks for your suggestion.. yes thats the formula i was looking for.. also, i didnt use proper naming, regarding joins as mentioned above I didnt use them jus to keep the ques short..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CASE` is going to be applied to the aggregate, not individual bits.  Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(Average) FROM (
    SELECT 
            CASE 
               WHEN tb1.wpf = 0 THEN 0
               ELSE tb2.weight / tb1.wpf
            END AS Average 
        FROM Table1 tb1, table2 tb2 
) a
```

Comment: That changes the semantics of the original query. Which may have been wrong anyway.

Comment: thanks for your input but your answer completely changes my requirement

Comment: I'll fix the math... gimme a sec.